# Is there a way to see an older version of a file on the local network, via http://localhost:3000/?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm relatively new to RoR, and am trying to view an older git version through my browser.  I've used git show and the advice from http://bit.ly/fjIjva to view details about the older version, however, I want to be able to go to http://localhost:3000/ and actually view what the older version looked like.  Currently when I connect to the rails server, I can only view the current git version.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check out that file, but what you probably want to do is check out a previous *revision*. The command for this is `git checkout`. The manpage will tell you more about how to specify a revision and so on.

Comment: Thanks Rein!! I used the man page (http://bit.ly/79dV0) and git checkout master^^ to check out a previous REVISION :)